# AWS Directory Services - how long to create?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services

Im just wondering how long it usually takes to create a new AWS AD. I created one and after 15 minutes of the status `Creating` I deleted it (fearing pending failure). I then created another one, and let AWS pick the subnets - thinking that might speed up the process, but I am sitting at 20 minutes ... is this a normal amount of time to wait? I really don't have any visibility into what it might be doing, other than `Creating` ...

Comment: It's setting up Windows EC2 instances and installing all the software, setting up backups, probably rebooting a couple of times. If it takes more than 12 hours I might start wondering, until then just leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks... and yes it took a little longer than expected but nothing unreasonable. I think it was 15 minutes, but makes automation hard.

Comment: CloudFormation will wait that long for resources to be created and available, or you can have multiple templates / pipeline stages. Please answer your own question as it will help people in future :)

Comment: I just answered this. Thanks for the comments @Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this took a bit longer than other (non-Windows) resources that I am used to creating. In fact Im not entirely sure my first attempt didn't silently fail. However a second attempt succeeded somewhere between 10-15 minutes. Hopefully that is good awareness for others needing to automate this.